# simulate AR time series data in r

Tags: r, time-series

I use `arima.sim` to simulate AR(1) process.

```
error.model = function(n){rnorm(n, sd = 1-0.3^2)}
X1 = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar = 0.3), n = 1e3, n.start = 2e2, start.innov = rnorm(200, sd = 0.3), rand.gen = error.model)
```

The variance X1 converges to 0.9.
But theoretically, since the variance of white noise is `1-0.3^2`, the variance of X1 should be `(1-0.3^2)/(1-ar^2)=1`

Answer (score -1):

I made a mistake. the `sd` should be `sqrt(1-0.3^2)`. So everything is fine now